# Jmeter: Response data is not loaded completly

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter

I'm trying to test a web page.for few request response data is not getting loaded completely, I can see only first few parts of a page. Where as for few request its working fine.Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: can you attach a screenshot or something to be even more clear of what you mean by "not getting loaded completely"?

Comment: Im not able to see the complete contents of a web page in jmeter response data.however if i take the request  from jmeter output and use it in any browser, im getting complete content of the page in browser.Only in jmeter (html) it shows first few data of the page.

Comment: when you say response not getting loaded do you mean getting loaded in "view result tree" listner

Comment: @ Vikas Madhusudana :Yes in view result tree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are viewing in view result tree then you should set

```
view.results.tree.max_size
```

in jmeter.properties

by default it is 200KB

```
# Maximum size of HTML page that can be displayed; default=200 * 1024
# Set to 0 to disable the size check and display the whole response
view.results.tree.max_size=204800 # set a value higher than default 204800
```

or set it 0 for no check

Comment: Yes i was just showing  where to see in jmeter.properties you have to set it to a higher value